# Substitute 'Group By' & 'Having' query with 'ALL'

Tags: sql, sqlite

The schema:

```
Movie(mID int, title text, year int, director text);
Reviewer(rID int, name text);
Rating(rID int, mID int, stars int, ratingDate date);
```

I made this simple query which returns the max movie rating, per film.

```
select title,stars from movie join rating Using(mID)
group by title
HAVING MAX(stars)
```

I've been trying to make this query without using `Group By, Having and MAX`, but I can't seem to get my query working.

This is what I have so far:

```
select title,stars from movie join rating r1 Using(mID)
where stars >= 
    ALL(select stars from rating r2 where r1.rID=r2.rID AND r1.mID=r2.mID)
```

And this just seems to throw me this error: `near "all": syntax error:` and I'm using DB browser for SQL Lite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select title, stars
from movie M1 join
     rating
     Using mID
group by title
having MAX(stars)
```

Doesn't do anything sensible -- with respect to the `having` clause.  All it does is filter out rows where `max(stars)` is not zero or `NULL`.  Probably not what you intend.

My guess is that you want the movie with the highest star rating.  If one such movies is fine:

```
select title, max(stars) as stars
from movie M1 join
     rating
     Using mID
group by title
order by stars desc
limit 1;
```